# dryIOC container implementation for webapi 2 project c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I'm really new to VS C# and coming from JAVA(Spring) background I'v embark my self in doing a POC with  Webapi 2 and VS2013.
So now I'm stuck at the DI container creation so I'm going to use [dryIoc](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc)  but I'm not sure exactly how to create one? even better how to do one that  automatically  scans your entire classes-models-repository  and figures out what are the dependencies.

Any good Articles tutorials on how to do this, best practices patterns?
What I've found in the [docs](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/Home)  is not completely clear on where exactly do I put this code or how to do it so that it scans folders/classes.

**EDIT**:
Clarifying: this is what I'm trying to accomplish :

1. I need to create a DI IoC Container based on dryIoC. [Why dryIoc](http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison)
2. Cannot use [Unity](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection).
3. A way for the container to scan the classes and automatically register them, not one by one.

Comment: Searching for tool/articles is off-topic on SO. You question is also very unclear in what you have problem with...

Comment: Ideally, you should be registering the mappings than scanning and loading. We've used Unity and configuration is best way to go

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm sorry just trying to learn, have not found other resource...

Comment: @saravanan because of requirements we can't use Unity

Comment: The idea was not to suggest unity, its about configuration of the mappings

Comment: WebAPI2 and ASP.NET MVC share a lot of common start up conventions.  Try searching for DryIOC and MVC:
https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/issue/44/sample-use-with-aspnet-mvc

Comment: @JAT2007 - "A way for the container to scan the classes and automatically register them" is very different from title of your post. You may actually want to ask 2 separate questions if you need help with 2 different aspects of using that library.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [sample](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/src/6f5496c12a8a7133bae20a5715773cd86979234b/Extensions/DryIoc.WebApi.Owin.Sample/?at=default) with DryIoc, WebApi, and OWIN.

For batch / automatic registrations you may use [RegisterMany](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/RegisterResolve#markdown-header-registermany).